# vim: project wide auto suggestion

Tags: function, vim, autocomplete

When using eclipse upon pressing control space, it show a list of all possible matching function calls irrespective of the file locations.

[image]

Is there a similar plugin for VIM ?

Answer (score 1):

I am using vim7.4 and shougo's neocomplete (https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim).  I actually switched from shougo's `neocomplcache` to this plugin. I am so far satisfied with the auto-complete feature provided by the nice plugin.

I don't write php code though, I made two screenshots of one of my python project.

### screenshot 1,

left side is a module `tmux_cmd.py`, right side I have imported the module, when I type the module name, the plugin suggested me all functions/variables in that module.

[image]

### screenshot 2,

in same module, when I type keywords (`load`) in this case, the plugin shows me all possible functions. I opened `tagbar` on right side to show functions in the current module. I can press `<TAB>` to choose the one I want, or keep typing something else if I just want to have something else, like `loadnothing....` In the screenshot I pressed `<tab>`

[image]

Comment: but are these auto suggestion buffer limited to the files that you have opened up in vim or do they suggest function's from files that are not open in vim but reside in your project directory ?

Comment: @VihaanVerma I just did a test, the file not opened in vim will be suggested. E.g. screenshot 1, I open the right side py file only, I can see the same popup as suggestion.

Comment: I know, this post is quite a few years old, but is there something new? I search for autosuggestion like in PhpStorm. So not only the options from LSP and open buffers. Something what provides my self made classes, namespaces, methods etc.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to index your project with ctags (see `:help tags` and `:help ctags`) and vim's built-in omni completion will do what you want for PHP when you press `<c-x><c-o>`.

Vim doesn't do auto-completion, though, you'll need a plugin for that like the one cited by kent but there are others.